# Receiving service messages in a group chat using Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to create a bot in my group to help me track the group users who have invited other users into the group.

I have disabled the privacy mode so the bot can receive all messages in a group chat. However, it seems to be that `update.message` only gets messages supplied by other users but not service messages like `Alice has added Bob into the group`

Is there any way that I can get these service messages as well?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using `python-telegram-bot` library.

You can add a handler with a specific filter to listen to service messages:

```
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters

def callback_func(bot, update):
    # here you receive a list of new members (User Objects) in a single service message
    new_members = update.message.new_chat_members
    # do your stuff here:
    for member in new_members:
        print(member.username)

def main():
    ...
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.new_chat_members, callback_func)
```

There are several more service message types your bot may receive using the `Filters` module, check them out [here](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.status_update).